# angular cli "ng serve" stdout

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I do "ng serve" output usually looks like this:

Hi there,

When I do „ng serve“ I usually see this output on my terminal window:

```
i ï½¢wdmï½£: Compiling...

Date: 2019-03-18T08:34:08.482Z - Hash: 555e9035303b34b1a371 - Time: 141ms
5 unchanged chunks
i ï½¢wdmï½£: Compiled successfully.
i ï½¢wdmï½£: Compiling...
i ï½¢wdmï½£: wait until bundle finished: /
```

What puzzles me is the characters "i ï½¢wdmï½£". I am working on windows and use the cygwin shell and terminal.

Question is: "What is this?"

Comment: can you shared your package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ï½¢` is the UTF-8 code for `｢`

`ï½£` is the UTF-8 code for `｣`

It's usually displayed as:

`i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.`

It might be the case that your cygwin installation does not use the UTF-8 charset.